# error in uploading image using com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest

Tags: java, servlets, image-uploading

HTML code:

```
<form action="go" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>
<input type="image" src="MainUpload.png"/>
</form>
```

Servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

//System.out.println("vlaue is:::"+s);
MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"D:/data");
out.print("successfully uploaded");
}
}
```

I want the user to upload an image which gets stored at the specified location.
This code was given to me by a friend and it was working fine there. But on my laptop the code's not working. I created a new dynamic web project copied file from src,web content and web.xml. and added an external jar file from "cos-26Dec2008" (which i downloaded from servlet.com ) There is no compiler error. I get a runtime exception :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest
UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:15)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: You have the `cos-multipart.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: user3805231 that is needed by the project. (That contains the class MultipartRequest). You have to add it to the classath of your server.

Comment: What is server you use? tomcat?

Comment: yes tomcat and i m using eclipse galelio

Comment: download the jar and copy the file in the lib directory of your tomcat.

Comment: Not to `bin` to `lib`

Comment: I tried both cos.jar and cos-multipart.jar

Comment: in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat5.5` should be a `lib` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `cos-multipart.jar` to the lib Folder of your Server.

Comment: @Nivedita I have added my solution as answer. Feel free to upvote/accept this if it has helped.

Comment: I added the jar file in the: my project in eclipse->web inf->lib and it worked .. thanku Jens bdw :)